# Deleted branches after 'git fetch -p'

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-fetch

I try to delete several branches from my project:

```
leo:Project leo$ git push origin --delete effects
To https://github.com/gituser/Project.git
 - [deleted]         effects
leo:Project leo$ git push origin --delete viewport
To https://github.com/gituser/Project.git
 - [deleted]         viewport
```

But after `fetch --prune` that says

> After fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer
>   exist on the remote.

I still have deleted branches on local machine:

```
leo:Project leo$ git fetch -p
leo:Project leo$ git branch -a
  develop
  effects
* master
  viewport
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you need to call `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master`?

Comment: effects and viewport are local branches which are not deleted by git fetch prune.

Comment: @MrTux can I check that branch hasn't any remote tracking references?

Comment: @d33tah it doesn't help, pls see upd

Comment: remote tracking references are located under remotes/*/HERE, those will get removed by git fetch prune, but local branches will not (even if those track a remote tracking reference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command did exactly what it said, it deleted "remote-tracking references". This means that any local branch that is connected to a branch on the remote repository gets disconnected, nothing more. That means in particular that the local branch still exists afterwards.

In order to delete a branch, use `git branch -D <branchname>`, perhaps make sure you don't lose any commits by first looking at the branch's content.

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch --prune` only removes remotely deleted remote references in your working tree. Remote references are located under `remotes/*` (e.g., `remotes/origin/master`).

`git fetch --prune` does not delete local branches - even if a local branch tracks a remote reference it doesn't get removed (e.g., by setting `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master`). This is intended. Imagine you have a local branch with some commits on it and then someone deletes the remote branch and your local changes are gone.

In order to delete local branches issue `git branch -D NAME`, however, make your you don't have commits on that branch you might want to keep.